Problema de enrutamiento proyecto Angular + Laravel
Subí mi proyecto formado por Angular (Frontend) y Laravel (Backend) a Cpanel. Es una academia LMS. Por preferencias personales no daré el dominio que uso, y usaré el ejemplo: cursos.midominio.com
Mi backend está en cursos.midominio.com/api
Ya que soy principiante seguí este tutorial
Y todo relativamente bien, pues en la página principal se muestra el contenido que se debe mostrar (los cursos, etc. que deberían salir), y no estoy recibiendo errores en la consola. Esto nos indica que las solicitudes al backend están correctas.
Sin embargo, al intentar acceder a alguna ruta, ej: cursos.midominio.com/todos-los-cursos/, cursos.midominio.com/mi-cuenta o cursos.midominio.com/info-del-curso, me encuentro con esta pantalla:

"404 | Not found" y nada en la consola.
Hay rutas a las que sí puedo acceder, como por ejemplo: cursos.midominio.com/contenido-del-curso/aprende-a-cocinar/, y se muestra todo lo que debe mostrarse ahí, sin embargo, al refrescar la página soy enviada nuevamente a la pantalla de not found.
Haciendo experimentos, subí el index.html del dist generado al hacer el ng build del frontend, y le di prioridad en el .htaccess, y de este modo todas las rutas funcionaron, todas sin excepción, pero el backend dejó de dar la información que debería. Así que obtenía la página que quería, pero no su contenido. Y también estos errores en la consola:
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://midominio.com/api/ecommerce/home", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/home", error: {…} }
​
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp;</title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…' }
​​
error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
​​
text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp; Education Bootstrap5 Template</title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…'
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/home"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/home"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
main.a53c2b4065b68a5f.js:1:159694
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/cart", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/cart", error: {…} }
​
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp; </title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…' }
​​
error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
​​
text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp; Education Bootstrap5 Template</title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…'
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/cart"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/cart"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
main.a53c2b4065b68a5f.js:1:159694
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/extras", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/extras", error: {…} }
​
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp; Education Bootstrap5 Template</title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…' }
​​
error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
​​
text: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n  <base href="/">\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">\n    <title>Home - Online Courses &amp; Education Bootstrap5 Template</title>\n    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n\n    <!-- Favicon -->\n    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">\n\n    <!-- CSS\n\t============================================ -->\n    <style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark…'
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/extras"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
url: "cursos.midominio.com/api/ecommerce/extras"

No sé realmente, pero parece que las solicitudes del backend están siendo respondidas con el código del index.html. Retrocedí mis pasos y lo dejé todo como estaba al inicio, es decir, eliminé el index.html y dejé el .htaccess nuevamente así:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Es en este punto en el que les solicito ayuda, pues he preguntado de todas las maneras que he podido a ChatGPT y buscado en internet, sin buenos resultados hasta ahora...
¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto? Y, claro, evitando conflictos entre index.html e index.php, o eliminando el index.html pero que las rutas funcionen
Necesito su ayuda, y se las agradezco de antemano.
Estoy usando

Angular 15.2.8
Laravel 8.83.27

Mi api.php:


<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\CartController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\ReviewController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\CheckoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\RepertorioController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Coupon\CouponController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Course\ClaseGController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Course\CourseGController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Tienda\ProfileClientController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Course\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Course\SectionGController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Discount\DiscountController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Repertorio\OpcionGController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Repertorio\CancionGController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Repertorio\RepertorioGController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

// Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// });

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('/login_tienda', [AuthController::class, 'login_tienda']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh'])->name('refresh');
    Route::post('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me'])->name('me');
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
], function ($router) {
    Route::resource('/users', UserController::class);
    Route::post('/users/{id}', [UserController::class, "update"]);
    Route::get('/roles', [UserController::class, "roles"]);

    Route::resource('/category', CategoryController::class);
    Route::post('/category/{id}', [CategoryController::class, "update"]);

    Route::get('/course/config', [CourseGController::class, "config"]);
    Route::resource('/course', CourseGController::class);
    Route::post('/course/{id}', [CourseGController::class, "update"]);
    Route::resource('/course-section', SectionGController::class);

    Route::resource('/course-clases', ClaseGController::class);
    Route::post('/course-clases-file', [ClaseGController::class, "AddFiles"]);
    Route::delete('/course-clases-file/{id}', [ClaseGController::class, "RemoveFiles"]);

    Route::get('/coupon/config', [CouponController::class, "config"]);
    Route::resource('/coupon', CouponController::class);
    
    Route::resource('/discount', DiscountController::class);

    Route::get('/instructor/{slug}', [ProfileClientController::class, "instructor"]);

    Route::resource('/repertorio', RepertorioGController::class);
    Route::post('/repertorio/{id}', [RepertorioGController::class, "update"]);
    Route::resource('/repertorio-cancion', CancionGController::class);
    Route::resource('/repertorio-opcion', OpcionGController::class);
    Route::post('/repertorio-opcion-file', [OpcionGController::class, "AddFiles"]);
    Route::delete('/repertorio-opcion-file/{id}', [OpcionGController::class, "RemoveFile"]);

    Route::get("/tienda-repertorio/{slug}", [RepertorioController::class, "repertorio"]);

});

Route::group(["prefix" => "ecommerce"], function($router) {
    Route::get("home", [HomeController::class, "home"]);
    Route::get("config_all", [HomeController::class, "config_all"]);
    Route::post("list_courses", [HomeController::class, "listCourses"]);
    Route::get("course_details/{slug}", [HomeController::class, "course_details"]);
    
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
    ], function ($router){
    Route::get("/user", [ProfileClientController::class, "user"]);
    Route::get("course_leason/{slug}", [HomeController::class, "course_leason"]);
    Route::post('/checked_clases/{slug}', [HomeController::class, "CheckedClases"]);
    Route::post('/last_class/{slug}', [HomeController::class, "LastClass"]);
    Route::post('/apply_coupon', [CartController::class, "apply_coupon"]);
    Route::resource('/cart', CartController::class);
    Route::post('/checkout', [CheckoutController::class,"store"]);
    Route::post('/profile', [ProfileClientController::class,"profile"]);
    Route::post('/update_client', [ProfileClientController::class,"update_client"]);
    Route::get('/extras', [ProfileClientController::class, "HeaderExtras"]);
    Route::get('/my_learning', [ProfileClientController::class, "MyLearning"]);

    Route::resource('/review', ReviewController::class);
    });  
});



Mi app-routing:


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './modules/auth/service/auth.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/tienda-guest/tienda-guest.module").then(m => m.TiendaGuestModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/tienda-auth/tienda-auth.module").then(m => m.TiendaAuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import("./modules/auth/auth.module").then(m => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'error/404'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }



Mi tienda-guest-routing.module


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TiendaGuestComponent } from './tienda-guest.component';
import { CoursesDetailsComponent } from './course-details/course-details.component';
import { FilterCoursesComponent } from './filter-courses/filter-courses.component';
import { InstructorComponent } from './instructor/instructor.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TiendaGuestComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'info-del-curso/:slug',
        component: CoursesDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'todos-los-cursos',
        component: FilterCoursesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'instructor/:slug',
        component: InstructorComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TiendaGuestRoutingModule { }



Mi tienda-auth-routing.module


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TiendaAuthComponent } from './tienda-auth.component';
import { ListCartComponent } from './list-cart/list-cart.component';
import { ProfileClientComponent } from './profile-client/profile-client.component';
import { CourseLeasonComponent } from './course-leason/course-leason.component';
import { RepertorioComponent } from './repertorio/repertorio.component';
import { MyLearningComponent } from './my-learning/my-learning.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: TiendaAuthComponent,
  children: [
    {
    path: 'cesta-de-compra',
    component: ListCartComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'mi-cuenta',
      component: ProfileClientComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'mi-curso/:slug',
      component: CourseLeasonComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'recetas/:slug',
      component: RecipesComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'continuar-viendo',
      component: MyLearningComponent
    }
]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TiendaAuthRoutingModule { }



Por favor haganme saber si necesitan ver algún componente o archivo, bendiciones, gracias.

En la doc de angular tienes cómo configurar un proxy para redirigir ciertas rutas a tu API: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server . Por este mismo motivo yo prefiero usar un subdominio para mi API cuando la despliego junto con el front, apicursos.tudominio.com nunca interfiere con cursos.tudominio.com/loquesea

Ahora estoy usando un subdominio para mi api, como lo mencionaste, Benito. Es mucho mejor. Te lo agradezco, esto que aprendí es muy útil.
